# Jupyter Notebook's File and Kernel menus disappear

Tags: file, jupyter-notebook, menu

I have an issue where my File and Kernel menus initially show while the notebook is loading, then disappear once the notebook is loaded.

I should be seeing this:
[image]

but instead I see this:
[image]

It used to work correctly. I am not sure what could have changed to make these menus disappear.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to your Virtual enviroment of python.
So what you can do for solving this issue, just create a new virtual enviroment from Python command prompt and change your virtual environment to the new one, which you created, or change your virtual environment to one of your existing virtual environments.

See list of virtual environment: conda info --envs (in the python command prompt)

Activate a virtual environment: conda activate * (* = name of one of existing virtual environments)

create a new virtual enviroment: conda create * (* = name of the virtual environment you want to create)

or if you do not want to change your virtual environment you can open your jupyter directly from anaconda)

another solution is that you can shift to jupyter lab which is more efficient with respect to the jupyter notebook.

in the python command prompt instead of writing "jupyter notebook", write "jupyter lab".

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem a few days ago, also a kernel error popped out. The error said that there was a problem with path to ArcGIS software, which I had installed couple of weeks earlier. After I uninstalled ArcGIS (I didn't need it anymore) my jupyter came back to normal.